# Pandas: creating values in a column based on the previous value in that column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Quick example:

Before:

```
In  Out    
1    5    
10   0    
2    3
```

After

```
In  Out  Value    
1    5   -4    
10   0    6    
2    3    5
```

So the formula here is `Value(rowx) =  Value (rowx - 1) + In(rowx) - Out(rowx)`.

I started with adding a Value column where each cell is 0. I then have looked a shift() but that uses the value in the previous row from the start of the command/function. So it will always use 0 as the value for Value. Is there a way of doing this without using something like iterrows() or a for loop ?

Comment: it think you will have to use loop - normally it puts new results to column after calculation for all rows but you need new results in column after every row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems in your calculations you could first calculate `In - Out` and later use `cumsum()`

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'In': [1,10,2],
    'Out': [5,0,3]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Value'] = df['In'] - df['Out']
df['Value'] = df['Value'].cumsum()

print(df)
```

or even shorter

```
df['Value'] = (df['In'] - df['Out']).cumsum()
```

Comment: That worked. I added .fillna(0) in my actual data cause In and Out can be NaN ( empty spots in the CSV). But great, thank you